# org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth.ValidatorFactory is already

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly

I'm getting below errors with Wildfly 8.2 trying to run standalone.sh:

And with Hibernate Validator:

```
16:18:14,731 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
16:18:14,798 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."auth-server.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."auth-server.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "auth-server.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth.ValidatorFactory is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:158) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:235) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:767) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:223) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2401) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:317) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.beanvalidation.BeanValidationFactoryDeployer.bindServices(BeanValidationFactoryDeployer.java:103)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.beanvalidation.BeanValidationFactoryDeployer.bindFactoryToJndi(BeanValidationFactoryDeployer.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.beanvalidation.BeanValidationFactoryDeployer.deploy(BeanValidationFactoryDeployer.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

How do I reuse with same service name or "jdni-name" and re-register so I can use the same service name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

It was standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.0"> 
  <auth-server name="main-auth-server"> 
    <enabled>true</enabled> 
    <web-context>auth</web-context> 
  </auth-server> 
</subsystem>
```

This was the problem
I had to remove  bit inside
Keycloak upgraded to new version two days ago and they haven't upgraded their documentation.

Hope this helps people trying to integrate new KeyCloak version